Most optimal way to transport objects from A to B with multiple workers
Disclaimer: I don't have any formal education in STEM by any mean and just want to clear up an argument I had with some of my coworkers
To provide some context, me and some of my coworkers had to move lots of objects from point A to C. I was going directly to point C to drop off my stuff when they said that their method was faster:

Split the group of workers into 2
The first group (which is the largest group) would deposit their stuff at point B, which is exactly between A and C
The second smaller group would pickup the objects at point B and bring them to point C
When there is nothing left at point A, the first group would then help the second group finish their task

They would argue their method is faster because "each of us don't need to travel back as far as your method, so theoretically it's faster". I said that it made no difference and they were just making things more complicated
Who is right?
For this problem, assume that each person can only transport one object at a time, we all travel at a constant speed, and we all start at point A and finish at C

The answer of 5xum rebuts your friends' arguments.  Despite this, your friends are right, specifically because humans are not robots.  Using their approach, they have more frequent rest stops where they are walking back empty handed.  This is both physically and psychologically more refreshing.

Given your assumptions, both methods are equally fast, and both workers travel the same distance. Take for example a simple case where there are only two workers for, say, 100 objects. Then

in your method, each worker takes 50 items and carries them to $C$, then goes back to $A$, so they travel $50$ full distances encumbered, and $50$ full distances unencumbered (traveling back).
In their method, each of the workers caries each of the items, but they only carry it half way, so they make $100$ half distances encumbered, and $100$ half distances unencumbered. But $100$ half distances is the same as $50$ full distances.

A difference appears if the workers both start at $A$, since then for the second method, one of the workers must first travel to $B$, so they will travel slightly more. But this difference is very minor and could also go the other way, if the workers already start split up, then the first method will cause slightly more travel.

However, what all this math is hiding is the fact that human beings are not simple machines. You assumed that you travel at a constant speed, no matter the distance and the weight carried. It's harder to carry a load one kilometer than it is to carry it $500$ meters twice, because in the second case, you get to rest your arms in between. On the other hand, there is some "overhead" in picking up the object, so it probably doesn't pay to carry the object $1$ meter $1000$ times.
So in reality, what you have is a more complicated optimization problem, where you are balancing the benefits of resting your arms versus the benefits of not having to pick up the item as many times.
It's important, in considerations like your own, to avoid oversimplifying the problem, to the point where at some point you start thinking that 9 women can deliver a baby in one month :)

Okay, I've tested it out on paper... and it seems like my coworker's strategy is quicker. I tried it with 13 boxes and 3 coworkers. Assuming it takes 1 second to go from point A to point B, it takes 18 seconds to complete the task using my method and 16 seconds using their method. Could you elaborate on your point when you said there might be some differences? I'm not sure I understood. Do you also have an example where my strategy is quicker? By the way, you make a good point; we're humans, not robots ;)

@MrSteak In your tests, what were the distances between the points? And what was the assumed speed? And was the speed assumed to be equal with or without carrying a box?

@MrSteak In general, as long as no box travels backwards at any point, the time spent actually carrying boxes will always be the same. So the only difference may come from workers travelling back to pick up the boxes.

@MrSteak Also, as long as no worker travels forward without a box at any point, and is never stationary, the total time will also be the same regardless of how much and how far they are carrying.

When you say "I tried it with 13 boxes and 3 coworkers" , your calculations seems to be wrong , @MrSteak , it will take only around 9 seconds in both methods.
